# How does charge density affect the rate of a decomposition?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

For example, for the thermal decomposition of carbonates of group 2 metals, how does the charge density decreasing down the group affect the rate of this decomposition?

Answer (score 1):

Increase in charge density increases the polarizing capacity of the atom, decreasing the bond strength, thus facilitating easy decomposition

Comment: timaeus, you should have posted what you did as a new answer, not as an edit to an existing answer.